# ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number 3 had an illegal value

Tags: python

i am trying to run a python code in the visual studio code. In the fourth loop it is showing the following error:"** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number 3 had an illegal value". please help me fix this.

i am trying to calcu;ate the displacement using the stiffness matrix

Comment: Could we see some code please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.